# extraneous digits formatting within dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am running into a formatting / precision issue which I'm hoping to control

I obtain a list of numbers such as:

```
x = [0.009947, 0.009447, 0.008947]
```

The finished product I'm after is a DataFrame with a column whose value is this list but multiplied by 100 with 3 decimal places, e.g.

```
[0.995, 0.945, 0.895]
```

I proceed as follows:

```
x = 100*np.around([0.009947, 0.009447, 0.008947],5)
```

this displays as

```
array([0.995, 0.945, 0.895])
```

When I build the DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame({'test':[x]})
```

I get for the value in the 'test' column:

```
[0.9950000000000001, 0.9450000000000001, 0.895]
```

This does not happen in other examples and I'm not sure how to control the behavior. Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

This is a general issue with the usage of floating points in computers, check this out
[from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)